# Defined function not seen as a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am confused why react native is not seeing this function timeToString(time) defined and called in my code as a function.  I get a nasty error that the function is not a function when app is run.  Please assist. thanks.

```
 export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
    };
  }

  timeToString(time) {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return (
      date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
    );
  }

  loadItems(day) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const strTime = this.timeToString(time);
        if (!this.state.items[strTime]) {
          this.state.items[strTime] = [];
          const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
          for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
            this.state.items[strTime].push({
              name: `Item for ${strTime}`,
              height: Math.max(50, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)),
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Error reported in red screen:
[image: Error reported in red screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadItems` needs proper scope of `this`

You can define it in constructor `this.loadItems = this.loadItems.bind(this);`

or

Use es7 fat arrow functions to define loadItems

```
loadItems = (day) => {
...
};
```

`timeToString` never calls `this` in it's execution so not required to bind it.

I, however, just define all of my class functions with the es7 fat arrow functions for auto-binding when needed.

Answer (score 0):

that's not related to react or react native

it is simply scope problem.

Not sure how you are calling this method, but you should make sure `this` is binded properly.

1: you can bind on the constructor in advance

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.timeToString = this.timeToString.bind(this)
}
```

2: bind in the call itself

export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
       render() {
           return (
               
           )
       } 
   }

Comment: i modified my code per your suggestion but got an error "self" is not a variable.  I then changed self to that and got the same error as before "that.timeToString is not a function. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: show me the code that calls this method? is it passed by props to somewhere? paste rest of the code

Comment: loadItems() doesn't have same scope as the class. It either needs this bound in constructor or defined with arrow function.

Comment: Here's the entire code.  ESLINT or ES6 does not allow using bind(this) but encourages use of arrow function instead. 

export default class AgendaScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
    };
  }
  loadItems(day) {
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + (i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const strTime = that.timeToString(time);
        if (!this.state.items[strTime]) {
          this.state.items[strTime] = [];

Comment: timeToString(time) is called from the loadItems(time) function given earlier from within the setTimeout() arrow function.  here: <Agenda
        items={this.state.items}
        loadItemsForMonth={this.loadItems}
        selected="2017-05-16"
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        renderEmptyDate={this.renderEmptyDate}
        rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged}
      />
    );

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using arrow function so you no need to refer this to that. When you use arrow functions the scope will available within it.

Note: The scope won't be available only when you use normal functions like

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 1000)
```

So your code looks fine in terms of scope. The issue I echo is you are not declaring/binding a function i.e., this.timeToString().

So bind your function in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
    };
this.timeToString = this.timeToString.bind(this)
  }
```

Hope this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Tzook Bar Noy, I finally figured out the issue.  I needed to also convert loadItems() that calls the timeTO String() function into an arrow function as a way to bind both and keep them in scope.

Problem solved.